# Unable to Access the BigQuery Errors Collection from an Airflow DAG Run

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am running a data transfer from Google Cloud Storage (GCS) into Google's BigQuery via the Python [GCStoBigqueryOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/gcs_to_bigquery/index.html#module-airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.gcs_to_bigquery) using Airflow (Hosted by Google Cloud Composer v2.5.4 with Airflow v2.6.3). The job fails with the following exception:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 2706; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details.
```

Prior stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/gcs_to_bigquery.py", line 442, in execute
    job.result(timeout=self.result_timeout, retry=self.result_retry)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job/base.py", line 922, in result
    return super(_AsyncJob, self).result(timeout=timeout, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/future/polling.py", line 261, in result
    raise self._exception
```

I understand that `bq --format=prettyjson show -j <JobID>` allows the viewing of bigquery errors inside cloud shell/any terminal, however there is no associated BigQuery JobID present inside the airflow logs.

**How can I access the errors collection when running a job in this way?**

I tried listing the bigquery jobs inside a cloud shell instance of my environment, and specified the time the job ran in the command, but it didn't return my job, I'm assuming because it never really executed.

```
bq ls --jobs=true --all=true \
    --min_creation_time=1707304500 \
    --max_creation_time=1707325200 \
    --max_results=10 \
    my-project-id
```